# Python dictionary returns keys in random order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple dict of dicts as follows:

```
stb = {
    'TH0':{0:'S0',1:'Sample1',2:'Sample2',3:'Sample4'},
    'TH1':{0:'Sa0',1:'Sample1',2:'Sample2',3:'Sample4'},
    'TH2':{0:'Sam0',1:'Sampled1.0',2:'Sampled2.0',3:'Sampled4.0'},
    'TH3':{0:'Samp0',1:'Sample1',2:'Sample2',3:'Sample4'},
    'TH4':{0:'Sampl0',1:'Sample1',2:'Sample2',3:'Sample4'},
}
tb = stb

theaders = []
for k in tb.keys():
    theaders.append(k)
columns = len(theaders)
rows = len(tb[theaders[0]])
print(tb[theaders[0]])
print('Cols: ',columns)
print('Rows: ',rows)

for h in theaders:
    print(h)
`
```

The problem here is that, every single time I run this snippet, `theaders` has values in a random order.For example, First Run:

```
{0: 'Samp0', 1: 'Sample1', 2: 'Sample2', 3: 'Sample4'}
Cols:  5
Rows:  4
TH3
TH0
TH4
TH1
TH2
```

Second Run:

```
{0: 'S0', 1: 'Sample1', 2: 'Sample2', 3: 'Sample4'}
Cols:  5
Rows:  4
TH0
TH2
TH4
TH1
TH3
```

**Note:** This was never the case before but for some reason, it just started happening and I really need those keys in their correct order.

**Also Note:** Simply sorting this would not work as the real data has string keys that **should not** be sorted.

Comment: dicts retain insertion order as of 3.7, prior to that `OrderedDict`  is required

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For python 3.6, dictionaries maintaining insertion order is an implementation detail.  In python 3.7 it's guaranteed and documented.  You didn't specify which version of Python you're using but I assume it's earlier than 3.6.  One option would be to use an ordered dictionary, OrderedDict from the collections module, where insertion order is guaranteed for older versions of python.

Comment: This is probably it, I am using 3.5 since it comes with Ubuntu Xenial. But how is it that it used to work well,earlier or was I just being lucky?

Comment: You were just lucky before and/or didn't notice =)

Comment: I guess, well..let me try it and see

Answer (score 3):

That is because *dictionaries are unordered* in Python. If you are looking to retain the order of keys, you should try `OrderedDict` as follows.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

stb = OrderedDict(
    TH0 = {0:'S0',1:'Sample1',2:'Sample2',3:'Sample4'},
    TH1 = {0:'Sa0',1:'Sample1',2:'Sample2',3:'Sample4'},
    TH2 = {0:'Sam0',1:'Sampled1.0',2:'Sampled2.0',3:'Sampled4.0'},
    TH3 = {0:'Samp0',1:'Sample1',2:'Sample2',3:'Sample4'},
    TH4 = {0:'Sampl0',1:'Sample1',2:'Sample2',3:'Sample4'},
)

tb = stb # As I see, this is not necessary (as we are not using std anywhere in the 
         # following code)

theaders = []
for k in tb.keys():
    theaders.append(k)

columns = len(theaders)
rows = len(tb[theaders[0]])

print(tb[theaders[0]])
print('Cols: ',columns)
print('Rows: ',rows)

for h in theaders:
    print(h)
```

Comment: In the real code, this is a utility class so `stb` is parsed in on initialisation and some cleaning up is done, so yeah..its necessary, but probably not necessary in this example..Thanks anyway